# Why the zero value still can submit even I already add some display error message there?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, css, forms

This is my code. I already set the display error message in PHP code. But it looks like the display error message not working when all of the element is empty. It can submit the empty value in a database.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>  
<html>
<head>
<style>
.error {color: #FF0000;}
</style>
</head>
<body>  

<?php
// define variables and set to empty values
$nameErr = $emailErr = $genderErr = $websiteErr = "";
$name = $email = $gender = $comment = $website = "";

if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
if (empty($_POST["name"])) {
$nameErr = "Name is required";
} else {
$name = test_input($_POST["name"]);
}

if (empty($_POST["email"])) {
$emailErr = "Email is required";
} else {
$email = test_input($_POST["email"]);
}

if (empty($_POST["website"])) {
$website = "";
} else {
$website = test_input($_POST["website"]);
}

if (empty($_POST["comment"])) {
$comment = "";
} else {
$comment = test_input($_POST["comment"]);
}

if (empty($_POST["gender"])) {
$genderErr = "Gender is required";
} else {
$gender = test_input($_POST["gender"]);
}
}

function test_input($data) {
$data = trim($data);
$data = stripslashes($data);
$data = htmlspecialchars($data);
return $data;
}
?>


<p><span class="error">* required field.</span></p>
<form method="post" action="add.php<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>">  
Name: <input type="text" name="name">
<span class="error">* <?php echo $nameErr;?></span>
<br><br>
E-mail: <input type="text" name="email">
<span class="error">* <?php echo $emailErr;?></span>
<br><br>
Website: <input type="text" name="website">
<span class="error"><?php echo $websiteErr;?></span>
<br><br>
Comment: <textarea name="comment" rows="5" cols="40"></textarea>
<br><br>
Gender:
<input type="radio" name="gender" value="female">Female
<input type="radio" name="gender" value="male">Male
<span class="error">* <?php echo $genderErr;?></span>
<br><br>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">  
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

**Here is my form action code add.php**

```
<?php

mysql_connect("localhost","root","") or die("Cannot connect");
mysql_select_db("testingdb");


$name= $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$website =$_POST['website'];
$comment=$_POST['comment'];
$gender=$_POST['gender'];

$result=mysql_query("INSERT INTO information (name , email, website, comment, gender) VALUES ('$name' , '$email' , '$website' , '$comment' , '$gender')");


if($result){
echo ("<SCRIPT LANGUAGE='JavaScript'>
window.alert('SUCCESSFULLY ADD!') 
</SCRIPT>");
}
else {
    echo ("<SCRIPT LANGUAGE='JavaScript'>
window.alert('FAILED TO ADD!')
</SCRIPT>");
}

?>
```

Comment: You need to validate the request data in `add.php`. (Your other PHP validation occurs *before* the browser even receives the HTML, so that's not validating what the user entered.)

Comment: your problem is you validate the form in wrong place. see my answer.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing stopping the form from being submitted, even if you add custom error messages to it. HTML is not advanced enough to identify error messages you have added and so the form will submit as normal.

Answer (score 0):

You are testing if `$result` is truth. If it is then you display the success message.

What makes you believe a empty value will set `$result` to a false value? Are you expecting the database to return a `false` value?

You need to add more validation of the value/s you are passing to the database **before** you pass them if you what to avoid passing an empty value.

Answer (score 0):

Well You never end up validating your form because your form will be submitted to `add.php` rather than the page containing validation rules it self. So below is shown what you should do:

```
<?php
// define variables and set to empty values
$nameErr = $emailErr = $genderErr = $websiteErr = "";
$name = $email = $gender = $comment = $website = "";
$error=false; // set error state to false

//if its a post request
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {

    function test_input($data) {
        $data = trim($data);
        $data = stripslashes($data);
        $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
        return $data;
    }


    //validation rules
    if (empty($_POST["name"])) {
        $error=true;
        $nameErr = "Name is required";
    } else {
        $name = test_input($_POST["name"]);
    }

    if (empty($_POST["email"])) {
        $error=true;
        $emailErr = "Email is required";
    } else {
        $email = test_input($_POST["email"]);
    }

    if (empty($_POST["website"])) {
        $website = "";
    } else {
        $website = test_input($_POST["website"]);
    }

    if (empty($_POST["comment"])) {
        $comment = "";
    } else {
        $comment = test_input($_POST["comment"]);
    }

    if (empty($_POST["gender"])) {
        $error=true;
        $genderErr = "Gender is required";
    } else {
        $gender = test_input($_POST["gender"]);
    }

    //eof of validation rules


    //if there is no errors
    if(!$error){
        // connect to database and do your stuffs
        mysql_connect("localhost","root","") or die("Cannot connect");
        mysql_select_db("testingdb");


        $name= $_POST['name'];
        $email = $_POST['email'];
        $website =$_POST['website'];
        $comment=$_POST['comment'];
        $gender=$_POST['gender'];

        $result=mysql_query("INSERT INTO information (name , email, website,comment, gender) VALUES ('$name' , '$email' , '$website' , '$comment' , '$gender')");


        if($result){
            echo ("<SCRIPT LANGUAGE='JavaScript'>window.alert('SUCCESSFULLY ADD!')</SCRIPT>");
        }
        else {
            echo ("<SCRIPT LANGUAGE='JavaScript'>window.alert('FAILED TO ADD!')</SCRIPT>");
        }
    }else{  
    //show the forms with errors 
?>
<!DOCTYPE HTML>  
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            .error {color: #FF0000;}
        </style>
    </head>
    <body> 
        <p><span class="error">* required field.</span></p>
        <form method="post" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>">  
        Name: <input type="text" name="name">
        <span class="error">* <?php echo $nameErr;?></span>
        <br><br>
        E-mail: <input type="text" name="email">
        <span class="error">* <?php echo $emailErr;?></span>
        <br><br>
        Website: <input type="text" name="website">
        <span class="error"><?php echo $websiteErr;?></span>
        <br><br>
        Comment: <textarea name="comment" rows="5" cols="40"></textarea>
        <br><br>
        Gender:
        <input type="radio" name="gender" value="female">Female
        <input type="radio" name="gender" value="male">Male
        <span class="error">* <?php echo $genderErr;?></span>
        <br><br>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">  
    </form>

</body>
</html>
<?php
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: had some missing braces.

Comment: what framework do you use? I use Adboe dreamweaver, it say got error there

Comment: Okay. I already copied. The error message is working but, if I wanna submit (got values in element) there got error. Here is it. 
Fatal error: Call to undefined function test_input() in C:\xampp\htdocs\SPKPKG\testfile\test2.php on line 11

Comment: Answers should have explanations.

Comment: well @WilsonEntering the error is clear it says the function `test_input` is not defined yet so paste the function `test_input` at the top of the validations as I've done..

Comment: @chris85 I've add some explanations

Comment: @WilsonEntering plz check if your problem is fixed now by copying all of above code and run

Comment: You should add that this code is for `add.php` and add a note about SQL injections. The `test_input` does nothing to prevent injections.

Answer (score -1):

There are a number of problems with the way in which you're attempting to insert the data, but I believe the reason that you're not having *any* output is because standard `mysql` commands are deprecated as of PHP 5.5, and *removed* as of PHP 7.0. Instead, you should be using MySQLi, or preferably, PDO. You'll need to restructure you code to use either, and I recommend reading up a bit on them first.

See http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php and 
http://php.net/manual/en/class.pdo.php for further instructions on how to use them. PDO is more secure, but harder to learn, and not all web hosts support it -- make sure to check with your hosting provider!

One thing both methods push heavily is prepared queries. Without using a prepared query, you're leaving yourself vulnerable to SQL injection. A prepared query binds the parameters being passed through, so they can't be manipulated.

Here's a sample MySQLi prepared statement:

```
 if ($insert_stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO members (username, email, password) VALUES (?, ?, ?)")) {
     $insert_stmt->bind_param('sss', $username, $email, $password);
     if (!$insert_stmt->execute()) {
         // Insert failed
     }
     // Insert was successful
 }
```

Comment: Can someone explain exactly *why* my answer was down-voted? I believe my answer to be helpful and pertain to the problem at hand. If it is not, can you please let me know why?

Comment: I not understand PDO syntax. Not expert yet. Hmmmm

Comment: This isn't PDO @WilsonEntering, and using out of date functions/code will only hurt you further down the road. Prepared statements should be used.; I think this answer was downvoted because it doesn't address the validation issue which the OP is asking about (although the SQL injection issue should be addressed).

Comment: because the problem you described has nothing to do with the question and user does not want to know about `mysqli`

Comment: @ASK - The question asker stated that they were not getting any output from their query, which uses MySQL commands. I stated that it is likely due to the fact that MySQL commands have been deprecated since 5.5 and removed since 7.0. If they are using PHP 7, there will not be any output. My answer provides a direct possible reason for the question asker's problem existing. Please explain to me how that is not relevant? Also, if you could tell me where the question asker specifically stated that they were adverse to MySQLi?

Comment: I don't see an issue with `mysqli` however the OPs query did/does execute successfully (with the test values at least). It didn't use the validation. `It can submit the empty value in a database.`